# UITableView Input Field Being Covered

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a strange issue. When I load my tableview that contains two textfields (one for email and one for password), I am only able to see the bottom of the cursor. It is as if there is something covering the input field (please see the image below). This issue only started when I went from targeting iOS6 to iOS7.

Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = 10;
    frame.origin.y = 10;
    frame.size.height = 30;
    frame.size.width = 200;

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: frame];

    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
    label.text = [arrayLogin objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    frame.origin.x = 10;
    frame.size.height = 90;
    frame.size.width = 280;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {//user name part
        userNameTextField = [[UITextField alloc ] initWithFrame: frame];
        userNameTextField.returnKeyType  = UIReturnKeyDefault;
        userNameTextField.delegate = self;
        userNameTextField.placeholder = @"Email";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:userNameTextField];
    }else
    {
        passwordTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        passwordTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
        passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
        passwordTextField.delegate = self;
        passwordTextField.placeholder = @"Password";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:passwordTextField];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: the problem occurs on iOS6 ?
if so I would advice to make label background color as clearColor.
please try it and tell me what you get , I think the label overlap the upper part of your tetield

Comment: Only noticed it when upgraded app to iOS7

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and still get the same issue. I even tried removing the entire label and still have the problem

Comment: you only have 2 rows ? first for username and seccond for password ?

Comment: Yes. Those are the only two rows I am working with

Comment: what is the row height ? default height is 44 (not sure should check)
if you did not change it at `heightForRowAtIndexPath'
this will exceed row height `    frame.size.height = 90;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default row height is 44 (not sure -anyway close to it.)

In your code you are using  `frame.size.height = 90;` which you are adding as subView in your cell. 
So it is exceeds your cell height.

To make custom cell height you should change the following delegate method:

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    //NSLog(@"HeightForRow");
    return 44+50;//ofcourse change it as you wish
}
```

also I think you want to change the `frame.origin.y` for the textField to 42
and text `frame.size.height` to 90 -42